# k8s readiness probe - command with http get

Tags: kubernetes

this question is about k8s readiness probe.
I am trying to add the command in readiness probe curl to the new pod that is creating.

I mean that I want to check that the new pod that is created is ready to accept traffic, before the old one is terminated.
I alrady have a command that is execute in the readines probe, so it is not possible for me to add an httpGet in this way:

```
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /health
```

because I saw that there is an [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/37218) that it is not possible to add httpGet & command that will be execute.

Therefore, I must add this curl to the script that is running each time before new pod is created.

```
status=$( curl -s -o -k /dev/null -w %{http_code} /health); echo "statusCode: $status" if [ "$status" -ne "200" ]; exit 1 fi
```

My problem is that that it is not working, and using `kubectl describe po XXXXX` I see this output:

```
 Readiness probe failed: statusCode: 000000 if [ 000000 -ne 200 ]
```

So, I'm not sure how to make request to the new pod, because the only thing that I know about the new pod in this level is that it include an api named **health**.

am I making the request correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some colons and a then.

You have:

```
status=$( curl -s -o -k /dev/null -w %{http_code} /health); echo "statusCode: $status" if [ "$status" -ne "200" ]; exit 1 fi
```

instead of

```
status=$( curl -s -o -k /dev/null -w %{http_code} /health); echo "statusCode: $status"; if [ "$status" -ne "200" ]; then exit 1; fi
```

Comment: Thanks, it's my first time with shell script. now the only error is "Readiness probe failed: statusCode: 000000" which is the most important for me to know how to send request to the new pod, do you have any idea?

Comment: It is a bit unclear who destroys/creates the pods or if you need more than the readiness probe. When readiness probe will return "Succeed" (when your status is 200), then kubernetes will use start sending requests to that pod (for example if you have a service configured). If you have more questions about that, please accept this answer and start a new question (describing complete scenario - who creates/destroys/how many services/etc.). This question is about your readiness probe not working and I think we solved that.

Comment: Can you try using this command (changing the order of `-k` and `-o`) as `-o` option should be directly followed with file path which in your case is `/dev/null`

`status=$( curl -s -k -o  /dev/null -w %{http_code} localhost/health); echo "statusCode: $status"; if [ "$status" -ne "200" ]; then exit 1; fi`.

If you are using different port than 80 than also specify it in the path along with `localhost`

Comment: thank you, adding the full path with localhost solved and adding full path of the commands solved the problems for me.

  `status=$(/usr/bin/curl --noproxy "*" -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://localhost:1880/ping);
   /bin/echo "new pod http request status code: $status";
   if [ "$status" -ne "200" ]; then
        exit 1;
   fi`